# React.js passing data from class component to another in ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this problem where I want to update my component FooBar if Foo's state changes. How can I do it? This doesn't work.

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import FooBar from "./FooBar"

class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
       super()
       this.state = { data: [] } 
   } 

   changeData() {
       someCode
   }

   render() {
       return (
           some html
       )
   }
}

ReactDom.render(<Foo />, document.getElementById('Something'))
ReactDom.render(<FooBar data={this.state.data}/>, document.getElementById('SomethingElse'))
```

Comment: why are you using 2 ReactDom.render??? create a new parent component and render both foo and foobar in that. so only one reactdom. render is required and you communication problem is solved

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think that somehow!

Comment: Please follow the react tutorial to understand some basic before dive in your work

Comment: I have written this as answer

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit confusing, You can try this if it works

```
 changeData = () =>
       this.setState({data:'your changes'})
   }
```

the above code will update the state, thus rest of component connected with class will render automatic.

Comment: I have this FooBar component that is in another file and I want to send some props to it when this Foo updates it's state and this FooBar doesn't render in Foo class, does this make my question make more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent component, render both foo and foobar inside. now you can use state normally for communication between them and only have to use one ReactDom.Render

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return(
        <div>
           <Foo/>
           <Foobar/>
       </div>
      );
   }
}


ReactDom.render(<Parent  />, document.getElementById('Something'))
```